# HTML displaying text using variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a checkbox in HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
```

Now, I want `I have a bike` part i.e. the text that comes besides a checkbox to come from a variable. How can this be done?

Comment: From what kind of variable? Server-side? Client-side?

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="vehicle" />
<label for="vehicle" id="lblVehicle"></label><br />
<script>
var lblBike = 'I have a bike';
document.getElementById('lblVehicle').innerHTML = lblBike;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourTextVariable = 'I have a cool bike';
document.getElementById('vehicle').innerHTML = yourTextVariable;
```

Comment: @Sam actually question was tagged with html so i thought it would be JavaScript