# How to add "like" button to html blog page?

Tags: html, blogs

How do I add a simple like button that is NOT associated with facebook? I have searched online, but most of the instructions are for facebook likes. I think this should be fairly simple, but I am a very amateur to html. Please help. Thanks. I just a button like this:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read this:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp
it helps you understand how to add buttons into html and if you want to keep trace on the amount of likes that it gets just add some code and variables you can read about that here:
[HTML displaying text using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753778/html-displaying-text-using-variable)
i think that you would only need to make the button add +1 to a variable and that variable would be the one displaying the amount of likes.
hope it helps.
you should end up having something like this :  jsfiddle.net/YdhTQ/64

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Here what I have is: `<i class="mdi-action-favorite red-text text-lighten-1"></i> <a href="#">0</a>` What I want is after I click the '0', it will add one. How do I do that? thanks.

Comment: you will have to add some code, instead of zero just make it a variable and everytime someone clicks it add 1 to that variable and so on, just use the <script></script> things and you could use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11753956/5063263
aaand this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956138/how-to-add-1-to-a-javascript-variable-by-clicking-a-button

to add the variables

Comment: something like this: jsfiddle.net/YdhTQ/64

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have it tied to actual server code try this if you want the number to just increment everytime it's clicked and I'm hoping you're using jquery:

```
<i class="mdi-action-favorite red-text text-lighten-1"></i> <a href="#" onclick="AddValue()">0</a>

<script>
var startingNumber = 0;

function AddValue()
{
   startingNumber++;
   $(this).text(startingNumber);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But when I click on the '0', it is not increased by one.

Comment: I added the `<script>...</script>` in my header and `<i...>...</i><a...>...</a> ` in the place where I want my like button to be. Is that correct?

Comment: Script should be at the end of the page. Put the onclick="AddValue()" in the a href tag